# should you import/export the whole class implementation from another file, or create an interface to import/export

Tags: interface, architecture, export, software-design

Lets say I have a class A that imports class B to use it for referencing. Is it - according to standard software design principles - advised to create an additional interface of class B that gets imported by class A? Does this save memory because only the interface, rather than the whole class implementation needs to be imported by class A? Is it worth creating an extra interface for every class no matter how big, also regarding to the naming of the interface/class (as `I` as a prefix is not recommended to use for interfaces (reference Clean Coder))

#### Example (in typescript):

**Withouth interface**
class A:

```
import B from "path-to-class-b";

class A {
    private B referenceToInstanceOfB;

    constructor(referenceToInstanceOfB: B) {
        this.referenceToInstanceOfB = referenceToInstanceOfB;
    }
}
```

class B:

```
export default class B {
    ....
}
```

**----------------------------------------------------- vs. ---------------------------------------------------**
**With interface**
class A:

```
import IB from "path-to-interface-b";

public class A {
    private IB referenceToInstanceOfB;
    
    constructor(referenceToInstanceOfB: IB) {
        this.referenceToInstanceOfB = referenceToInstanceOfB;
    }
}
```

class B:

```
export default interface IB {
    ...
}

class B implements IB {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an interface instead of a class enables the concept of [Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)).  This is a powerful, fundamental concept of object oriented design, and is key for many of the foundational design patterns such as the [Gang of Four design patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns).  It also is very powerful when isolating tests to the code under test instead of more complex object graphs.

Whether it is worthwhile for you depends entirely on your design considerations.